# Compilar un Proyecto de Eclipse con solo la consola y javac

Tags: java, consola

Alguien tiene la idea de como compilar un proyecto de eclipse, con solo la línea de comandos, por lo regular lo he hecho con Ant/maven o gradle, pero ahora me han solicitado a mas bajo nivel con comandos directos para usarlo directo en server.

Algo como esto:

```
javac -cp ./somelibs .d ./somedirectory
```

Actualmente mi .classpath en Eclipse ese este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 6 [1.6.0_65-b14-468]"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/com.ibm.gwa.mq.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/com.ibm.mq.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/connector.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/db2jcc.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/db2jcc4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/joda-time-2.3.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/sqlj.zip"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/sqlj4.zip"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

He estado buscando alguna herramienta para extraer esto a una linea de comandos pero no me funciona. Tendrán alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 2):

En la perspectiva de debug de eclipse da clic derecho en la ruta del javaw y luego en propiedades como muestra la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la ventana que aparece en la parte de Command Line, eclipse te muestra todo el comando que ejecuta para compilar tu programa que se esta ejecutando, incluyendo -vm options, jars asociados al proyecto y el punto de entrada de la clase main:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Excelente se ve muy bien, lo voy a probar y justamente es algo así lo que estaba buscando.